# scala spark Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am scala newbie and have recently started using spark and scala. I have a piece of code which simply reads and csv file and processes the rows and it's all running locally on my laptop. The code was working just fine and suddenly stopped working. The code looks like:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("testApp")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
val sc = spark.sparkContext

val ERROR_UUID = new UUID(0,0)

// Read data from input path
val data = spark.read.format("csv")
  .schema(inputSchema)
  .load(inputPath)
  .rdd

data.take(2).foreach(println)

val headerlessRDD = data
  .map {
    case Row(colval: String, colval2: String) => {

      val colval_uuid: UUID =
        Try({
          UUID.fromString(colval)
        }).recoverWith({
          // Just log the exception and keep it as a failure.
          case (ex: Throwable) => malformedRows.add(1); ex.printStackTrace; Failure(ex);
        }).getOrElse(ERROR_UUID)

      (colval_uuid, colval2_uuid, 45)
    }
  }.filter( x => x._1 != ERROR_UUID) // FILTER OUT MALFORMED UUID ROWS

val aggregatedRDD = headerlessRDD.repartition(100)
aggregatedRDD.top(5)
```

And the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Z)V
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec.compressedInputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapForCompression(SerializerManager.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.wrapStream(SerializerManager.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:64)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:628)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$32.apply(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$32.apply(RDD.scala:1475)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using spark 2.4.5 and can see `lz4-java-1.4.0.jar` in the `jars` directory. I've read some similar questions on stackoverflow and people pointing out the have the same issue but talking about kafka, but I am not using kafka at all. Also, I am running this code using IntelliJ  IDEA. And as I pointed out earlier, this was working just fine and not sure while it's throwing an exception right now. It's worth to mention that the problem goes away if I take the `repartition` part out! (which I am not planning to)